# Redux and within a reducer accessing a different reducer, how?

Tags: redux, react-redux

So, I have an app that has multiple reducers, and thus multiple action creators associated.

There is a time in which one of my reducers updates the state (because of an edit), and as such, I have to then make sure the other reducers see this update and adjust their state accordingly.

think of it as if a user selects "sneakers", and this state management is in a reducer called productsReducer. As such, as a user moves thru the app process, they get couponsReducer associated with it... but the user can "edit" at any time, so if they then edit "sneakers" and say, choose another producer, I have to be able to alter the couponsReducer in real time, because a progress modal needs to reflect this. I can do this via going thru the flow to the coupon page, because on that page I just reconcile the data on componentWillMount... but the rub is I have a progress modal, and prior to getting to the coupons page, a user can open the progress modal... and there will be a missmatch here...

long winded I know, I just wanted to explain my situation.

so, I want to be able to call "other reducers" or their action creators from within the productsReducer.

Would a middleware be appropriate here, in which I sniff for a certain "action.type" and if I see it, I can dispatch other action.type's or is there a way to call action creators from within the productsReducer?

importing: import * as coupons from './couponsActions' and any other actions I need seem inappropriate.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Updating state based on the state of application is an anti-pattern. The solution is even simpler:

If an action affects multiple reducers, subscribe to that action in the reducers that care.

So when a user selects `sneakers`, fire these actions

```
{ type: 'item_select', payload: 'sneakers' }
```

and then in `couponsReducer`, have something like this:

```
function (state = initialState, action) {
  if (action.type == 'item_select') {
    return { ...state, activeProduct: action.payload);}
  }
  return state;
}
```

You do not want cascading updates, where states depend on other states changing. You want a simple dispatch architecture where one action affects everything all at once.

Comment: awesome. My main concerns was staying within proper paradigm and not go anti-pattern. I am able to effectively do what I need by just, like you suggest, subscribing as I need. great, thanks.

Comment: "Updating state based on the state of application is an anti-pattern" ?  That doesn't make any sense.  The whole point of a reducer function is that you make decisions based on *current state* and the action.

Comment: @markerikson No, reducers are meant to handle actions, not changes in state. Changes in state should always be the _result_ of actions. Creating actions as a consequence of an action being dispatched is an anti-pattern.

Comment: Seems we have a terminology mismatch.  I think what you're trying to say is that "doing stuff based on _diffs_ in state is a bad idea"?  And I still disagree with your statement on actions, especially if you're using middleware.  It's totally valid to dispatch one action, have a middleware intercept it, and dispatch one or more other actions in response.  That's what middleware are there for.

Comment: Yeah, I think we're saying the same thing in that case. And you're right, I misspoke about actions--actions can beget other actions just fine, what is an anti-pattern is redundant actions or actions fired by reducers or because of changes to the store after the fact.

Comment: What is `state == initialState` in your example `function (state == initialState, action) ...`?
How dare you to pass FULL COMPLETE app state to specific reducer? What for do you break and separate reducers then if you pass FULL state to specific reducer? Either don't separate reducers or pass specific reducer state only `state == initialState.couponsState`.

Comment: @Green Thanks for pointing out the typo, I've fixed it. In my example I assume a single reducer with a single state object for simplicity, rather than assuming it uses a combined reducer. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

In many cases it is enough to handle the same action in multiple reducers (which is an officially recommended way of doing things in redux). So always try that solution first.

In more complex cases there are some libraries you can use. For example using [redux-saga](https://github.com/yelouafi/redux-saga) you could handle it like this:

```
function* watchItemSelect() {
    while(true) {
        // Wait for the action you are interested in
        const action = yield take('ITEM_SELECT');
        // Send another action
        yield put({type: 'OTHER_ACTION'}) 
        // The loop will now continue and wait until the next ITEM_SELECT action comes
    }
}
```

There are also other libraries that does the same thing but a little different. Most of them inspired by the elm language:

- [redux-loop](https://github.com/raisemarketplace/redux-loop)
- [redux-side-effect](https://github.com/gregwebs/redux-side-effect)
- [redux-side-effects](https://github.com/salsita/redux-side-effects)
- [redux-effects](https://github.com/redux-effects/redux-effects)

Also this repo has some info about the thinking in the above libraries:

[redux-architecture](https://github.com/jarvisaoieong/redux-architecture)

Comment: Add one more library in your app to solve your issue is not a solution. It is a 
bad design of initial library that is Redux.