# Is it possible to use getState() inside a reducer?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

The login reducer works fine but when I add a logout reducer, it doesn't work.

```
export const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    login: loginReducer,
    logout: logoutReducer
});
```

```
export const loginReducer = (state = initialState, { type, payload } :any) => {
  switch (type) {
    case "login":
      return {...state, token: payload};
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

I run a graphql mutation if login is successful, a token is returned, which is stored using redux. Later, this info is used to do private routing etc.

```
let submitForm = (email: string, password: string) => {
    setIsSubmitted(true);
    login({
      variables: {
        email: email,
        password: password,
      },
    })
      .then(({ data }: any) => {
        dispatch({ type: "login", payload: data.loginEmail.accessToken })
```

Now, i want to add a logout reducer. I want to logout if a button is clicked.
If I put this in my rootReducer, it compiles without an error.

```
const initialState = {
  token: null
};
const storeValue = store.getState();

export const logoutReducer = (state = initialState, { type, payload } :any) => {
switch (type) {
  case "check":
    return {...state, token: payload};
  default:
    return state;
}
};
```

However, if I do `state = storeValue`instead of `initialState`, I get errors on `storeValue` & `logout` definition that

`'storeValue'/logout implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in its own initializer.ts(7022)`

Edit:

This is how my privateRouting works:

```
export const PrivateRoute = ({ component, ...rest }: any) => {
  const routeComponent = (props: any) => {
    if(store.getState().login.token) {
      return React.createElement(component, props)
    }
    else {
      return <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/404' }} />
    }
  }    
  return <Route {...rest} render={routeComponent} />;
};
```

I have already mentioned above how I store my token within the `submitForm` function. Depending on this, how can I use the same `login` reducer to implement logout too?

```
<ExitToAppIcon onClick={logout}></ExitToAppIcon>
```

Comment: `store.getState()` returns an object which is combined/merged returned value of all reducers in your app. I can't see any usecase why would somebody need it in reducer. Can you explain your usecase?

Comment: A reducer is responsible for a slice of the overall redux state, it doesn't make any sense for it to see outside its area of responsibility.

Comment: @Danko Could you see the updated qs?

Comment: I think it makes more sense to use it in an action, grab some specific peice of state out of it, and then use it in your action logic before returning some new value to your reducer

Comment: @FSJ sure. Have added my answer below

Comment: You can access state though.

Comment: @zixuan how could I do so?

Comment: @SethLutske Could you please give an example? I also updated the qs according to the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

After some thinking (have not tested to be sure), I think that answer is no. You can't use getState() inside a reducer.

As far sa I understand how redux work (and I might be wrong, so double check it for yourself) - state is generated after all reducers get called first. So, `store.getState()` is probably `undefined` before the reducer(s) run for the first time.

Since you want to set initialState - you can't even do something like `store.getState().keyYouAreLookingFor` in order to use it in `logoutReducer`.

Comment: you can't indeed to use `getState` in a reducer. If you want to share some state from other data slices you could make your reducer to react to some other action. Also why to keep login/logout as separate data slices? Surely it could be single "login" reducer to handle both states.

Comment: Couldn't agree more with what you've said @Lukasz'Severiaan'Grela. Imo, single "login" reducer would be "a way to go". Having reducer to react to some other action could be messy. DIspatching action from some component to update one reducer - when props derived from other reducer get changed - could get even more messy. Let's have better state architecture (single login reducer) for the win FSJ

Comment: the action way is not bad, just not in this case. e.g. you have your different reducers but want to get the same data that other reducer receive so you make it to react to the same action. sometimes it works and sometimes you have to flatten your reducers:)

Comment: Hey, could you please see the updated qs and suggest how I could use the same login reducer for logout as well? Let me know if the info is sufficient. @Lukasz'Severiaan'Grela

Comment: @FSJ You didn't see my comment at all?

Comment: @zixuan thunk action has acces to state, but it does not mean reducer will. FSJ - reducer is modified by actions, your logout action will clear token. However I would make your component connected so it gets update asap;)

Comment: @Lukasz'Severiaan'Grela I DO NOT agree. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39257740/how-to-access-state-inside-redux-reducer.

Comment: your agreement dear @zixuan is not required, what you have linked is what I stated, thunk has access to  getState reducer Does not, you can use thunk action to provide data you need but this was also stated above.